# Signed applet still shows the UNKNOWN publisher

Tags: java, applet, certificate, signed-applet, thawte

I got a code-signing certificate from Thawte. I imported it with private key into the keystore (jks type). Then I successfully signed my applet using this certificate. BUT when I show the page with my signed applet it still shows the UNKNOWN publisher! When I check the certificate from this dialog window then I see that it signed by Thawte. What is wrong? What I should check? Thanks...

Comment: After I added intermediate certificates into the pair then it started working. So this is solved.

Comment: To "close" the issue, simply write your own answer and marked as the accepted answer. It saves others some trouble (or at least the trouble of looking at all of the comments. :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added intermediate certificates into the pair then it started working. So this is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for Legacy code signing (desktops) or for windows 8 apps? Usually a unknown publishers after signing has to deal with not having enough intermediateds associated with the certificate. These intermediates are responsible for connecting the certificate that was given to you and connect it to the root that is installed on the client machine.

If you dont have enough intermediates to chain to that root certificate or none at all you will get that error. below is a link that should point you in the right direction.

Unknown publisher error occurs after signing files with a Thawte Code Signing for Microsoft Authenticode (Multi-Purpose) certificate issued after July 15th, 2010
https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO16963&actp=AGENT_REFERAL

Comment: No, it is Java applet. But as I wrote. It is already solved. How I can close this issue?